# How to auto add quotation marks on a html string

Tags: html, string, vb.net

is it possible to add quotation marks on a html string in order to be userd in visual studio?
For example:

```
 class="btn btn-success btn-lg" href="
```

I want it to be

```
"class=""btn btn-success btn-lg"" href="""
```

so I can use it as string in visual studio.
So my question is:
Is it possible to create a little tool that, If I give ANY html It will give me back the html string already ready to be used in visual studio?
Thanks a lot

Comment: `Public Function EscapeQuotes(s As String) As String` `Return s.Replace("""", """""")` `End Function`?

Comment: I'm looking to find a way that is working with every kind of html string.

Comment: What do you mean _"working with every kind of HTML string"_? What is your end goal here?

Comment: Assuming by "closed", you mean "escaped", isn't that exactly what the function in my first comment does?!! Moreover, you don't really have to create a tool for this. A simple find and replace (in Notepad or something) would do the job.

Comment: If you pass `class="btn btn-success btn-lg"` to that function, it gives you `class=""btn btn-success btn-lg""`. It doesn't replace four double-quotations; it duplicates every single double-quotation in the input string (did you try it?) And you can also use the same function to enclose the whole thing in double quotes if you want (i.e., `"class=""btn btn-success btn-lg"""`). I'm not sure where the `href` part came from though. If what I proposed is not what you're after, you need to try and explain exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Does my first comment contain any specific HTML string? Are we both looking at the same thing?! To use this function, you'd read the HTML contents from a file or something (yes, any HTML or even any text that contains double-quotations) and you simply pass it to the function. Again, it's not even worth creating a tool for this. You would only need to use the function above if you want to _automate_ the task but if you just want to copy the escaped text to VS, you can simply use any text editor to achieve the same job using "Find and replace".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223426/discussion-between-41686d6564-and-mattia).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have to, you could write a function like this:

```
Public Function EscapeDoubleQuotations(s As String,
                                       Optional encloseInQuotes As Boolean = True) As String
    Dim escaped As String = s.Replace("""", """""")
    If encloseInQuotes Then escaped = """" & escaped & """"

    Return escaped
End Function
```

This will replace every double-quotation character in any text (not just HTML) with two double-quotations. This is particularly useful if you're trying to do this programmatically (e.g., to automate some task).

However, in my opinion, it's not worth creating a tool simply to escape the double-quotations. You can easily do that in any text editor (e.g., Notepad) using the "Find and Replace" utility. But if you think a tool would make things easier for you, then go ahead. You can use the function above to replace some text that is loaded from a file or manually added to a TextBox or something.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, That is working great! I didn't know I could do it with notepad using "find and replace", but definitely this little tool is useful for whenever I need to parse html text.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are adding the string to an HTML element but...

```
    Const bar As String = "class=" & ControlChars.Quote & "btn btn-success btn-lg" & ControlChars.Quote & " href=" & ControlChars.Quote & ControlChars.Quote
    '  produces   class="btn btn-success btn-lg" href=""
```

Comment: it misses two more quotes as my example

Comment: @Mattia - if you are adding this to an HTML element this is exactly what you'd need.  If you need additional quotes it should be obvious how to change this to get them.